# Foundation 12 Grid Does Not Work Properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have a code as below:

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left-frame large-3 medium-3 hide-for-small columns">
      <header class="icon-bar five-up" role="navigation">
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
      </header>
      <div class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
      </div>
      <footer class="pagination-centered">
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li class="arrow unavailable"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li class="arrow"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <div class="content large-9 medium-9 small-12 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-3 medium-3 small-12 columns">q</div>
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">q</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-3 medium-3 small-12 columns">q</div>
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">q</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want is 3 to 9 grids on a page. However, second column goes inside the first as below:

[image]

Why does that happen? It is surely 3 and 9. What I want is to get second column in its own place.

### Further Solutions Tried

## #1: Decrease the Second Column

I have made the second column 8 grid, an it works like a charm now. Strange. However, this way, it become 11 grid total.

---

## Environment

- foundation 5.5.3

Comment: I don't see second grid going inside . please check and update if i am missing any  http://jsfiddle.net/gRtrX/437/

Comment: Well, the version you specify is 5.2.3, but I use 5.5.3. When I try to use 5.2.3 gzipped Cloudflare CDN, some features are gone. Btw, edited, look above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine when tested in codePen example with your code, it may be your custom code that is conflicting.

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/5.5.3/css/foundation.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left-frame large-3 medium-3 hide-for-small columns">
      <header class="icon-bar five-up" role="navigation">
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
        <a class="item"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></a>
      </header>
      <div class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">q</a></li>
      </div>
      <footer class="pagination-centered">
        <ul class="pagination">
          <li class="arrow unavailable"><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
          <li class="arrow"><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>
      </footer>
    </div>
    <div class="content large-9 medium-9 small-12 columns">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-3 medium-3 small-12 columns">q</div>
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">q</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="large-3 medium-3 small-12 columns">q</div>
        <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns">q</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/shoaibik/pen/KrmdOJ

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is because columns are supposed to be wrapped by rows but you have column>row>column. In your situation you should utilise the `.hide-for-small-only` class and `.hide-for-medium-up`to get the results you want.